# R - psych::omega n.iter Error in pmax(eX$values, 0) : invalid input type

Tags: confidence-interval, psych

I try to conduct CIs for McDonalds Omega using the 'omega' function from 'psych'-package in R.
The following code worked for each subscale of my scale, using 3 or 4 items of the entire scale, but not for the entire scale (10 items in total).
Using the code 'psych::omega(data, n.iter = 10)' for my entire scale I always get the following error code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHkat.png)

Thanks for your help in advance! :)

I tried varying the number of bootstraps (n.iter = 2/ n.iter = 10/ ...). The code psych::omega also works perfectly fine without 'n.iter' but I seek to conduct the CI of my McDonalds Omega.